# What do the dog & laptop mean in the Stack Overflow Careers advertisement?

Tags: discussion, jobs, advertising

I know it might look like trolling but...

In the Careers ad below, you see a dog behind a laptop, and the ad says: "Work, From Home."

[image]

Why does the Careers team choose such a picture? What is the logic behind this to make the one who sees the ad more attracted to the ad?

In other words: What does the picture of a Dog & Laptop have in common with "Working From Home"?

It might be convenient in the culture of the advertising team, but me and my friend (who originally raised the question) don't know why, and knowing is good for us to get an idea of what ads should be like :)

---

**UPDATE:** NOW I can understand well! dogs work for Careers, Cats work for the rest of SE ;)

[image]

Comment: Isn't there anything better than being at home, with your laptop on the table and your beloved dog with you? Oh wait - I have cats!

Comment: ["On the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog."](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f8/Internet_dog.jpg)

Comment: @BilltheLizard post as answer?

Comment: The dog's name is Mr. Snuggles. While you might not know Mr. Snuggles, he is a well known figure in the Open Source hardware community. Mr. Snuggles is after all the creator of the the [BeagleBoard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard) (the name of which is hence fairly logical), despite the fact that Digi-Key and Texas Instruments claim to be key players. This is more of a marketing strategy than actual fact. Mr Snuggles, being a dog, was not allowed to work in the down-town office building. He has since become a vocal advocate for working from home. I guess that explains his appearance.

Comment: [Cats are community managers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155160/anna-lear) @Tamer.

Comment: Oh my God, I can't believe it! they're gradually controlling our world!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In many countries around the world (including the US, where Stack Exchange is based), dogs are considered to be prized companion animals. Many viewers will naturally get feelings of 'home' when seeing a photo of a dog. The photo is in a kitchen, with the laptop on a kitchen counter; this further emphasizes the idea of 'home'. Of course, the laptop represents 'work'.

I feel it perhaps instructive to note to some people that not all cultures see dogs the way many western cultures do; so I can see how it might be confusing to some to see such an image in such an advertisement.

Comment: Or, an ["on the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you're_a_dog) reference? Oh, I see Bill the Lizard already mentioned it. Well, that's what comes to mind for me, and I'm sure anyone creating the ad would have been savvy enough to know it would be emotive in that sense, would seem backwards to try and use it in another way on the web. From the west here, no idea that your suggestion would be a natural feeling for a majority.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you can work on your laptop (from home) while your dog is with you.

Comment: Next step: ask on Programmers or Code Review whether the dog should code the business or UI layer.

Comment: @Frédéric Fixed ambiguous wording :P

Comment: It's pair programming where half of the pair will be happy if you just throw it a bone every now and then.